# Adding integers concurrently with relevant ordering does not work as expected

Tags: rust

In one of his [great video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=rMGWeSjctlY), Jon Gjengset implements a mutex to notably understand the effect of std::sync::atomic::Ordering. The code is very simple : create a mutex that holds an integer and start many threads to add 1 to the integer concurrently and see the results. The code is here (I reproduce stricly Jon example) : https://github.com/fmassot/atomics-rust

When using correct ordering, we expect the program to make additions atomically and check the result as the sum of all added values. The code does several times on each thread the following actions :

- call compare_exchange_weak with Ordering::Acquire to get the lock
- on success increment the value by one
- release the lock with Ordering::Release

Unfortunately it does not seem to work on linux/x86_64 nor on macbook/arm64.

The results when running `cargo r --release` are sometimes correct, sometimes wrong like this:

```
thread 'main' panicked at 'assertion failed: `(left == right)`
  left: `985`,
 right: `1000`', src/main.rs:58:5
note: run with `RUST_BACKTRACE=1` environment variable to display a backtrace
I put the code here https://github.com/fmassot/atomics-rust
```

Currently I don't understand why the current implementation is not working, I'm quite new in rust and it may either come from a stupid error from me or something more subtle.

Thanks for you help!

Comment: Why are the constants `LOCKED` and `UNLOCKED` both true in your code?

Comment: oh my goodness.....

Comment: thank you very much, problem solved..... feel completely stupid right now

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem solved, solution given by @user4815162342

The same value was used for `LOCKED` and `UNLOCKED` so there was no lock at all.

Conclusion, the error was stupid and coming from me...